# How to collect requests by method from access.log

Tags: python-3.x

Good day, i'm trying to parse access.log  with python.
Example line from log-file:

109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "POST /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4494 "http://almhuette-raith.at/administrator/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" 4374

I wrote the following code:

```
    import argparse
    import json
    import re
    from collections import Counter
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Analize access.log')
    parser.add_argument('-f', dest='logfile', action='store', default='access.log')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    reg_ip = (r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")
    reg_date = (r"\d{1,2}\/\D{1,3}\/\d{1,4}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\s\+\d{1,4}")
    reg_method = (r"(POST|GET|PUT|DELETE|HEAD)")
    reg_statcode = (r"(200|400|500)")
    reg_url = (r"\http")
    reg_reqtime = (r"\"\s\d{4}")
    
        def req_meth():
           with open(args.logfile) as file:
             for index, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
                  try:
                      res_method = re.search(reg_method, line).groups()[0]
                      print(f"Number of Requests by method: {res_method}")
                      return Counter(f"Number of Requests by method: {res_method}")
                  except AttributeError:
                         pass
        with open("final_log.json", "w") as jsonfile:
            json.dump(req_meth(), jsonfile, indent=4)
```

I need to collect the number of requests for each of the methods. My code is not working right now, what should I fix?
Also I need the URL, status code, ip and request time to be displayed in the  resulting json file

Answer (score 0):

found this solution:

```
import argparse
import json
import re
from collections import defaultdict

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Код для анализа логов')
parser.add_argument('-f', dest='logfile', action='store', default='access.log')
args = parser.parse_args()

regul_ip = (r"^(?P<ips>.*?)")
regul_method = (r"\"(?P<request_method>GET|POST|PUT|DELETE|HEAD)")
regul_statuscode = (r"\s(?P<status_code>20[0-9]|40[0-9]|50[0-9])\s")
regul_url = (r"\"(?P<request_url>htt[p|ps]:\/.*?)")
regul_reqtime = (r"\s(?P<request_time>\d{4}$)")

dict_ip = defaultdict(lambda: {"GET": 0, "POST": 0, "PUT": 0, "DELETE": 0, "HEAD": 0})


with open(args.logfile) as file:
     for index, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
        try:
              ip = re.search(regul_ip, line).group()
              method = re.search(regul_method, line).groups()[0]
        except AttributeError:
               pass
        dict_ip[ip][method] += 1

print(json.dumps(dict_ip, indent=4))
```